# Modular Arithmetic and Greatest Common Divisor.

Tags: number-theory

In my algebraic structures textbook I have come across a tricky question that I am trying to solve which goes as follows:

suppose that $d|(a^n-1) $ and $d|(a^m-1)$ where  $m,n$ are natural numbers and $a,d$ are integers, then show that $ d|(a^{gcd(m,n)}-1) $ . What I know is that clearly $a^m$ and $a^n$ are congruent to 1 modulo d, and that by Bezout's theorem the $gcd(m,n)$ is of the form $k=xm+yn$ so that $a^{gcd(m,n)}$ can be written as $a^{xm}a^{yn}$ but I am not sure how to tie all these ideas together. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Let $xm-yn=\gcd(m,n)$ so that $x,y$ are positive integers.

Note that $a^{xm} \equiv 1 \pmod d$, and that $a^{yn} \equiv 1 \pmod d$.

Thus if $a^{\gcd(m,n)} \equiv t \pmod d$, $a^{yn}t \equiv 1 \pmod d$.

Comment: An alternate solution would be to use $ord_d(a)$, which divides both $n,m$.

Comment: How can you let  $xm-yn = gcd(m,n)$ such that x,y are positive integers?

Comment: @James Dickens : [bezout identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)

Comment: If $xm+tn=\gcd(m,n)$, only one of $x,y$ would be a negative number since $n,m$ are natural numbers. WLOG let $t$ be the negative number. Let $t=-y$.

Comment: Is it not adding not subtracting? sorry this may be a silly question

Comment: @JamesDickens While it is adding, one must be a negative number.

Comment: Did you understand? I cannot help but notice that you have not accepted any answers. Do you know how to accept answers? I am not implying that you should accept my answer in particular, but you have asked 26 questions, and accepted none of the answers presented.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry. I am still thinking about what you wrote. I definitely think you are right and appreciate the help. By accept answer I assume you mean click the check, which I will.

Comment: To be honest I still do not understand the last line of your hint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35430/discussion-between--and-james-dickens).